# swig, soap or restful for my c/c++ library

Tags: c++, web-services, rest, soap, swig

I have a library/API that is completely built with C/C++ for over 10 years (under Linux). Now I want to export the API as a web service for other web projects use. I search for the web and narrow down to the following 3 chooses:

1. use SWIG to export the API to PHP or other script/web base language
2. use gSOAP to export the API as SOAP protocol
3. export the API as RESTful service (I can't find any exist framework, any suggestions?)

I want to compare them in terms of

- stability
- easy of use
- performance

SWIG seems easy to use buy I am not sure the stability of it.
gSOAP seems very stable but a bit difficult to use and setup.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I personally used [WSO2-WSF-CPP](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/cpp/) which is a C++ layer on top of AXIS2/2 to export legacy C++ code as web-service.

I tried back then gSOAP which worked quite well, but for stability and deployment reasons I choose WSO2, since AXIS2/C can be deployed *easily* as a module of the well know Apache2 HTTP server.

For the *ease of use* requirement I don't know if you plan to take WSDL file as a template to generate source code skeleton, but you can forget about this feature of the WSO2 package ... It seems to have been deprecated for a long time and the generated code is way too ugly to be maintained by hand.

Although doing a code generator yourself could be a good idea depending on the complexity and the amount of services you have. I recommend it! I did that and creating/building/generating services is quite straightforward now.

Another thing to notice about the WSO2 web services is that it's simple to build out of the box, and comes with stand-alone server to develop and test with.  It was quite helpful (even if I am quite sure any decent web-service platform provides this kind of stuff like gSOAP does).